# sftp/fish over double hop with different users

Tags: ssh, sftp

I am trying to set a ssh session over a double hop with different users on each hop to transfer files easily via fish/sftp.

my .ssh/config look like

```
Host middle_server
    User            foo
    Hostname        192.168.xx.xx

Host www.server.org target
    User            bar 
    HostName        www.server.org
    ProxyCommand    ssh middle_server nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

The connection to middle server is secure by rsa key, and direct from the middle server to the target with the bar user.

When I try to connect to the target, I got the following error:

```
[foo@localhost]$ ssh target
Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa':
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I can connect with the 2 following methods, so I guess the bar user is not used for the second hop, but I have no idea of what can be the cause.

```
[foo@localhost]$ ssh middle_server
Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa':
[foo@middle_server ~]$ ssh bar@www.server.org
[bar@www ~]$
```

or

```
[foo@localhost]$ ssh -A -t foo@middle_server ssh -A bar@www.server.org
Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa':
[bar@www ~]$
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `ForwardAgent yes` for both?

Comment: I added `ForwardAgent yes` for both both hosts, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ProxyCommand` your *local* machine does the connection to target host. As you want to create the connection from middle to target, you should not use it (or should not use it with `nc`).

I would not use `ForwardAgent` since it is not totally secure (the user `root` on middle machine can encode data using your key using `ssh-agent` on your local machine).

So, one possible solution is to run `ssh` command in middle machine to target machine inside your `ProxyCommand` on local machine. For example:

```
ssh bar@doesnt_matter_host_here -o ProxyCommand='ssh foo@middle_server "ssh bar@www.server.org nc localhost 22"'
```

You can configure a host called "www_over_middle" with this `ProxyCommand` on your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host www_over_middle
    User bar
    ProxyCommand ssh foo@middle_server "ssh bar@www.server.org nc localhost 22"
```

And then:

```
ssh www_over_middle
```