# Two hop SSH with multiple user names

Tags: ssh, netcat, username

I am trying to set up an ssh proxycommand, where the user name at the final host is different from the user name at the original host.  I am logged in on firstHost as username and want to effectively run this command:

```
ssh middle ssh othername@target
```

I would like to be able to do this with

```
ssh target
```

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/414681/sftp-fish-over-double-hop-with-different-users) suggests using a proxycommand that does an ssh to target to run nc on target.  That makes the connection, but does not use the passwordless ssh that I set up.  Is there a way to get this to work with passwordless ssh?  (And is there a reason to use nc instead of making the proxy command `ssh middle ssh othername@target`?)

.ssh/config on firstHost looks like this:

```
Host middle
HostName middle.domain

Host target
User othername
Proxycommand ssh middle ssh othername@target.domain nc localhost 22
```

The output of ssh -vv target from firsthost is

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh middle ssh othername@target.domain nc localhost 22
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/identity type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
login banner from middle
login banner from target
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<4096<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 275/512
debug2: bits set: 1987/4096
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'target' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug2: bits set: 2053/4096
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2b9c1e95c4d0)
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
login banner
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Hostname cannot be canonicalized

debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Hostname cannot be canonicalized

debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Hostname cannot be canonicalized

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: So if you followed that post, and it works aside from the authentication, it sure would be nice if you posted the exact config you used and the output of `ssh -vv target` so we can see the error messages.  The examples suggested by that answer should work just fine, and is nearly identical to my working configs.  I could answer the why Proxycommand part, but I figure the main part of your question is about the authentication networking in the multi-hop setup.

Comment: Check http://superuser.com/a/484979/163736 for an example on how to use an SSH tunnel. You will have to adjust your local SSH config regarding the server (to instead connect to a given localhost port), but as the server is not directly accessible anyways, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias sshTarget="ssh -tA middle ssh -l othername target"
```

**Update**

```
ssh -N -L 4441:othername:22 middle 
scp -P 4441 /documents/foo localhost:/backup/
```

Comment: That works fine for ssh to target, but does not allow `scp target:file local_file` to work.

Comment: I see no mention of scp in your question. Try to ask about the problem rather than the wrong solution you have tried. See update.

Answer (score 0):

In 2016, SSH added some shortcuts to make it dead simple. Instead of your `ProxyCommand` with netcat, just put `ProxyJump middle` in the Host block for "target." Each server can have its own user and almost any other parameter from `ssh_config(5)`. You can chain hops together, too.

If you don't want to set up the config, you can do it all on the CLI with `-J`:

```sh
ssh -J me@middle othername@target
```

But you should set up the config. Then all you need to type is `ssh target` and everything works transparently.